# How to manipulate Mono Object with Kotlin

Tags: json, object, kotlin, spring-webflux, flux

Hi guys I am developing an API with webflux and kotlin.
My question is simple I need to manipulate the properties of the Flux object that returns me when consuming an API, this is the object that hurts me

```
postId": 14,
    "userId": 2,
    "title": "voluptatem eligendi optio",
    "comments": [
        {
            "email": "Janice@alda.io",
            "body": "necessitatibus libero occaecati\nvero inventore iste assumenda veritatis\nasperiores non sit et quia omnis facere nemo explicabo\nodit quo nobis porro"
        }
 ]
```

This is my controller which makes a request and returns the previous JSON object

```
fun getData(): Flux<Post> {

    return apiService.fetchPosts()
}
```

This is the code of the service with which I consume the API

```
@Service
class APIService {
fun fetchComments(postId:Int) =
        fetch("posts/$postId/comments").bodyToFlux(Comment::class.java)

fun fetchPosts() =
        fetch("/posts").bodyToFlux(Post::class.java)

fun fetch(path:String): WebClient.ResponseSpec {
    val client = WebClient.create("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
    return client.get().uri(path).retrieve()
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: _this is the object that hurts me._ What?

Comment: You can use map function on Flux/Mono